# sql if statement in where class

Tags: sql

Hi I have the below query where I need to have an if statement in where class.

```
    Alter procedure dbo.GetName(@id int, @statusDate VARCHAR(50))
begin
select id, name 
from customer
where id = @id and
IF(@statusDate = 'Active')
    status > GetDate()
ELSE
    status < GetDate()
end
```

Here status is a column of type date in customer table
@statusDate is the parameter I will be passing (Active or Inactive)
if active after the second 'and' I have to get status > GetDate() for todays date else status < GetDate().

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You cant have an if clause in a where clause like that but you can restructure your where to do the same thing.

Try this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetName(@id int, @statusDate VARCHAR(50))
AS
SELECT id, name 
FROM customer
WHERE id = @id AND
(
   (@statusDate = 'Active' AND status > GetDate()) OR
   (@statusDate = 'Inactive' AND status < GetDate()) OR
   (@statusDate IS NULL)
)
```

Comment: Case statement is not woking showing some Incorrect syntax in > place..so i am going with the first one. thanks

Comment: Sorry I'm not at a computer so cant test, have removed the case until I can test the syntax

Comment: i forgot to say a point i will be choosing @statusDate from a dropdown so i may select --Select-- the first one in the dropdown list since it is not a mandatory one. in that case???

Comment: If thats the case you could set the @statusDate variable to default to 'Active' or 'Inactive' so when no value is passed it will default to that value. I've updated my answer to default to 'Active'. One thing to mention if the user doesn't select anything from the drop down then you shouldn't pass in "--Select--" to the stored procedure, you should instead just not pass that variable at all.

Comment: I will be passing null if nothing is selected. so if its null this AND should do nothing. updated ur answer with null.

Comment: What do you want returned if @statusDate is null? Nothing or everything?

Comment: exactly to say its 'everything' if null is passed.

Comment: Edited answer should do what you want

Answer (score 0):

I think you can rid of the if statement refactoring a bit your SQL:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM  customer
WHERE id = @id and
(@statusDate = 'Active' and  status > GetDate()) or (@statusDate = 'Active' and  status < GetDate())
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you would use the boolean OR operator to achieve the same effect:

```
alter procedure dbo.GetName(@id int, @statusDate VARCHAR(50))
begin
select id, name 
from customer
where id = @id 
and (
    (@statusDate = 'Active' and status >= GetDate())
     or (@statusDate <> 'Active' and status < GetDate())
)
```

Comment: i may pass @statusDate as null. in that case do we need to modify the statement. if so how?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, OR logic such as Gavin and Massimiliano answers, can cause performance degredation.  This has lead to people trying many options such as follows...

```
IF (@statusDate = 'Active')
  SELECT id, name FROM customer WHERE id = @id AND status > GetDate()
ELSE
  SELECT id, name FROM customer WHERE id = @id AND status < GetDate()
```

.

```
SELECT id, name FROM customer
WHERE id = @id
AND status > CASE WHEN @statusDate = 'Active' THEN  GetDate() ELSE         0 END
AND status < CASE WHEN @statusDate = 'Active' THEN '99991231' ELSE GetDate() END
```

.

```
SELECT id, name FROM customer WHERE id = @id AND status > GetDate() AND @statusDate = 'Active'
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name FROM customer WHERE id = @id AND status < GetDate() AND @statusDate = 'Inactive'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, name 
  from customer
  where id = @id 
        and 'T' = case 
                     when @statusDate = 'Active' then case 
                                                         when status > GetDate() then 'T'
                                                      end
                     else case 
                             when status < GetDate() then 'T'
                          end
                  end;
```